# Is php the right language to program for a large json api such as mochi?

Tags: php, mysql, json, cron, mochi

So I am currently using django and the site goes down very often...
However, because of that i was thinking if a simpler solution of php is introduced in slurping in the games over to my db and s3 using the following api then i would not have to keep up with the django issues:
url: http://www.mochimedia.com/feeds/games/xxxxxx/all?format=json
This has over 13000 games including the flash file and game meta data.
Every day I will need a cron that makes sure that only new games are loaded in mysql and s3.
would that be an overkill for php running on a small aws ec2 ubuntu box with 1.7 GB memory?

Comment: Just so you know, you can change it to an xml stream rather easily: http://www.mochimedia.com/feeds/games/xxxxxx/all?format=xml   I know that isn't entirely related. But I use c# to communicate with the xml feed, which I find works just as well as the php code I wrote for the json side.  Just notice this was an old topic. But hopefully the xml reference may help someone else...

Answer (score 0):

Consider the upsides of the language: simplicity (low-learning curve), portability amongst shared hosting providers, and a cheap labor pool. If those *features* aren't what you're looking for, than chances are PHP isn't the right language.

Programmers don't chose PHP on its technical merits.